# Regular expression in google big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Query:

```
SELECT DebugData
CASE
 WHEN lower(DebugData) LIKE 'veri%' THEN 'Verizon'
 WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(LOWER(DebugData),r'^\d+$') THEN c.Network 
 ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(lower(DebugData),r'[^a-zA-Z]', ' ')
END
AS ActualCarrier
From table
```

Data:

```
DebugData  Correct_result  Current_result
310410?                    c.Network
302220?                    c.Network
Comcel2                    Comcel
Gig?                       Gig
```

Currently the query does not work for first 2 cases. I am sure that nothing to do with c.Network, because I also tried the statement below and it does not work.

```
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(LOWER(DebugData),r'^\d+$') THEN 'hi'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: in your previous question you have very specific requirement - `When DebugData contains ONLY digits, then it should take the c.Network but for a combination of digits and alphabets, it should replace the other characters and print only alphabets` - so the query does exacly this. if this is not what you meant - please re-formulate your "requirements".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meantime, try below - I think it captures that missing part of your requirements

```
SELECT DebugData
CASE
 WHEN lower(DebugData) LIKE 'veri%' THEN 'Verizon'
 WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(LOWER(DebugData),r'^\d+[^a-zA-Z]*$') THEN c.Network 
 ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(lower(DebugData),r'[^a-zA-Z]', ' ')
END
AS ActualCarrier
From table
```

Note: You should finalize your requirements at least for yourself and try to adopt above to your particular case

I would recommend to read [Regular expression functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regularexpressionfunctions) and [RE2 regular expression syntax reference](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)